# $a_n = 1+(-1)^n-\frac1n$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that the following sequence diverges:

$$a_n:=1+(-1)^n-\frac{1}{n}$$

How do I approach this when the sequence is in such a form?

Comment: Are you adding up the $a_n$'s?  Because the terms do not go to $-\infty$, they alternate between approximately 2 and approximately 0.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $a_n$ converges. Since $1/n$ converges, it is clear $a_n+1/n=1+(-1)^n$ converges. But...

Comment: But since (-1)^n is a divergent monotone sequence it must mean that $(a_n)+1/n$ oscillates between 0 and 2 and thus is divergent. How do I do this more formally?

Comment: Do you recognize the argument I gave as proof by contradiction? Or are you asking how to show that $a_n+1/n$ is divergent? I think your explanation is clear.

Comment: I recognise that your doing a proof by contradiction. How do i formally show that $1 + (-1)^n$ is divergent? That's my struggle

Comment: @Vladimir did you read my answer? The last sentence answers how.

Answer (score 3):

This sequence is bounded below by $-2$ because $$1+(-1)^n-\frac{1}{n} > (-1)^n -\frac{1}{n} \geq -1 -1 =-2.$$ However, the term $(-1)^n$ should give a hint that this sequence oscillates; the $1$ certainly doesn't stop the oscillation and also $-\frac{1}{n}$ gets too small to prevent the sequences from oscillating.

Instead, try to show that this sequence has infinitely many terms less than $0$ and infinitely many terms greater than $1.$

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into too much detail as I'm pressed for time but I found two subsequences of $(a_n)$ that have different real limits (0 and 2) and by definition this makes the sequence $(a_n)$ divergent.

Comment: Correct. this is the simplest method, well done.